# Conditional Sum in Excel that counts values above X as X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I have a column of values which I want to sum, but I want any values above 5 to only count as 5.
I can do this by having another column that changes the value to 5 if it's above 5 and then summing that column

`=IF(C4>5,5,C4)`

Is there a way to do this with a sumif statement or some other way to avoid having a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, formula in `B1`:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5,"<=5")+COUNTIF(A1:A5,">5")*5
```

[image]

An array-entered variant would be:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A5>5,5,A1:A5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the ones up to five and count the ones above 5.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A50,"<6") + 5*COUNTIF(A1:A50,">5")
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, should have specified that it includes decimals, so should be <=5 rather than <6.